# Запятые при вставных конструкциях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, вставная-конструкция

Какой вариант расстановки запятых правильный?

1. Он жил — так беззаботно и радостно жил — но всегда помнил о смерти.
2. Он жил — так беззаботно и радостно жил, — но всегда помнил о смерти.
3. Он жил, — так беззаботно и радостно жил — но всегда помнил о смерти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Он жил — так беззаботно и радостно жил, — но всегда помнил о смерти.

Розенталь: "Смеялся он мало — настолько у него хватало чувства такта, — но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах — вторая часть начинается с союза, перед которым должна быть запятая".